# Is it possible to delay or overwrite windows cannot find 'acrord32.exe' error message in java

Tags: java, adobe, acrobat

I need to use both executable files of Adobe reader to open documents.
acrord32.exe for the users using adobe acrobat reader and acrobat.exe for the users using adobe acrobat pro.
I have used system parameters to get done the job.
But my problem is that whenever I use the acrobat.exe version this error message is coming.

[image: acrord32.exe error message]

After clicking ok then my pdf file opens from acrobat.exe.

So I just want to delay/overwrite/remove this message by using java...

Here is my code

```
public static void openPDF(Container container, String fileName) throws Exception, PrintException {
   SystemParameterHome paramHome = (SystemParameterHome) container.getHomeForEntityBean();
   try {
    String pdfParameter = "PDF_COMMAND";
    SystemParameterObject pdfCommand = paramHome.findByPrimaryKey(pdfParameter);
    String command = pdfCommand.getStringValue();
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command + " \"" + fileName + "\"");
    int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
    if(exitVal != 0) {
        System.out.println("exit value in if: "+ exitVal);
         pdfParameter = "PDF_COMMAND_64";
         pdfCommand = paramHome.findByPrimaryKey(pdfParameter);
         command = pdfCommand.getStringValue();
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command + " \"" + fileName + "\"");
         throw new PrintException("There was an error in printing. Please contact a system administrator.");
         
    }else {
        System.out.println("exit value in else "+ exitVal);
    }
    
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: Sounds like you try to open the file with both programs instead of elegantly determining which utility is actually there, but since you didn't post code, no one can tell you what's wrong and how to fix it. Just a note for future reference: you should be handling edge and corner cases properly instead of just hiding them. The word for a programmer who habitually sweeps problems under the rug is "unemployed."

Comment: I'm sorry about that I thought this one should have a common answer. Anyway, I added the code. If you have any idea please let me know. Thank you